# Why would XML be an issue with a MEAN stack application, and what is this error about?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, express, socket.io

I am currently working on a socket.io "hello world" via a MEAN stack application, and right away Chrome is tossing some funky errors my way. To be honest, in the debugging effort, I'm not sure even where to begin. My initial questions were:

- Why is XML being used instead of JSON?
- What does **No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.** even mean?

The entire error message is below, and thanks in advance for any advice y'all are able to give.

Cheers,

Peter

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1435600202687-6. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:9000' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.
```

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` is used for far more than xml. as far as the error, use it as a search term in google.

Comment: you're not supposed to "ajax" that url, you need to feed it to a `new Socket`

Answer (score 0):

Try including the socket.io lib directly from the socket server:

```
<script src="http://localhost:9000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

The Error "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource." means that your server doesn't allow an extern resource to connect.

Additionally you can set the allowed origins directly in the io setup e.g:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(server, {origins:'page.com:* http://page.com:* http://www.page.com:*'});
```